# How do I show that g ◦ f = id, when I only have the information that f is injective?

Tags: inverse

Let f ∈ Hom(R3,R7) be an injective map, then there exists a g ∈ Hom(im(f), R3 ) such that g ◦ f = id.

We have that invertibility is equivalent to injectivity and surjectivity. But how do I show that g ◦ f = id, when I only have the information that f is injective?

Comment: A map of sets $f:X\to Y$ is injective if and only if there is some $g: f(X)\to X$ with $g \circ f = \text{id}_X$.

Comment: What do you mean by R3 and R7?

Comment: I meant ℝ^3 and ℝ^7

Comment: Define $g: \operatorname{Im}(f) \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ as $g(y) = x$, where $f(x) = y$. Since $f$ is an injective function it follows that $g$ is well-defined.